# Shortcut for text mode in Word equation editor

Tags: microsoft-word

In Word 2013, you can choose 'Normal Text' within editing an equation by going Design -> (Tools panel) -> Normal Text.

Is there a shortcut for this, I would usually use LateX but I have been imposed to write my docs in Word. I often have to type sections of text that would be more legible using the 'Normal Text' setting within an equation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you wish to type normal, non-italic text when in equation mode in Word, enclose it within double quotation marks. When you type "foo, Word shows foo in italic, but when you then type the quotation mark ", Word removes those marks and renders foo as normal text.

On the other hand, if you frequently need to type normal text inside equation mode, you might need to consider your notations. Normally equations should be written using mathematical notations only, and any verbal explanations should appear in the text. But sometimes you have a good reason to include words like “when” or “if” in equation mode; then just type "when" or "if".

Comment: In this case I am typing formulas for Financial ratios, they are often using entities like "Account Receivables", I could assign a letter for each but since they pretty much do not reuse the variables, it is likely to get more confusing.